# Create virtual Uri from a local photo

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to save a local image in the firestore database so that it can be accessed from different devices. The problem is that the image is saved with the address with which it is saved on the device itself and makes it impossible to open it from other devices.

The uri is saved like this:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/files/DCIM/IMG_20211019_174021266.jpg

What would be the best way?

Comment: The uri is ok. Of course from other devices that uri cannot be used. They should use the firestore uri of the image uploaded in your firebase. You should upload the image itself. Not a file path.